# Client- side (browser) 3D Viewer

Tags: browser, web, 3d

I am looking for a browser based viewer for 3D objects. The model(s) are going to be fairly large (millions of faces).

Additional requirements:

- GIS capabilities
- ability to stream the model
- smooth and fluid view

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

SpiderGL has a demo with streaming LoD terrain:

http://spidergl.org/example.php?id=8

This demo shows how to stream a large multiresolution terrain from an USGS dataset managing an internal cache and a request queue.

SpiderGL was created by the Institute of Information Science and Technologies (ISTI), an institute of the Italian National Research Council (CNR).

BTW, the development was some time inactive - current version is now just 0.2.0, but the demo is quite impressive and not to underestimate:

[image]

Comment: seems helpful to me- gonna check it out, thanks! /upvoting

Answer (score 0):

You can use [three.js](http://threejs.org/) or [jsc3d](https://github.com/humu2009/jsc3d). I've tested with large OBJ and PLY models.

Comment: what do you mean by "streaming"?

Comment: Streaming would be a 3d engine that's:

 a. Displaying sections relevant to your viewing position b. Displaying different LevelOfDetails per your viewing distance from each section c. Doesn't just download the whole model and attempts to display it (and incidentaly saves the model obj to disk from where the user can just grab it).

Comment: These are the best javascript engines I've tried. Probably with other technologies you can have more features.

Comment: perhaps what I'm asking for is just not feasible, either way cheeers for the help